# Send data in a http post in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, http-headers

I'm trying to send data with http post following differents threads, but I can't do it.
I need to send this data, tested in postman.

Headers.
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic user:pass

Body.
grant_type: password
scope: profile

This is my code.

```js
login() {

    let url = URL_LOGIN;

    let headers = new Headers(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic user:pass'
      });

    let body = {
      'grant_type': 'password',
      'scope': 'profile'
    }

    return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        var result = response.json();
        return result;
      })

  }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to modify:

1. Your headers passed into the http post method missed one step. It should contain the following:

   ```
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   ```

   Ensure you import `RequestOptions` from `@angular/http`

   Then pass `options` into your post method as follows:

   ```
   return this.http.post(url, body, options)...
   ```
2. The http post method body can only be a string. Therefore, it should be as follows:

   ```
   let body = 'grant_type=password' + '&scope=profile';
   ```